# How to show a column on desktop but collapse on tablet view using rappasoft laravel livewire datatables

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using the rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables package (https://rappasoft.com/docs/laravel-livewire-tables/v2/introduction) to create tables in my app. In general it is an upgrade of another project. However I am struggling with how the ->collapseOnTablet() works. Consider this Column def

```
return Column::make('id', 'id')
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable()
            ->collapseOnTablet()
            ->format(
                fn( $value, $row, Column $column) => '<span data-id="' . $row->id . '">' . $row->id . '</span>'
            )
            ->html();
```

So what seems to be happening is in desktop the column is completely hidden (incorrect). There is no option to expand either. when in tablet or mobile the column is hidden (correct) and the + icon is shown and when clicked it expands to show the fields (correct). How do I show the column on desktop as a normal column? Why would it work this way anyway? I thought at first it might be layout but it does exactly what I expect in Tablet mode.